# Bin variable with pre-defined bins and closed/open intervals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, binning

I have a set of bins which can be defined by:

1. A set of tuples of non-overlaping boundaries of each bin:

   Intervals: [(0,1), (1,2), (3,4)]
2. A set of indicators identifying which boundary of each tuple is closed:

   Closed_Boundaries: ['right','right','both']
3. A set of labels for each interval

   Labels: ['first','second','third']

I am looking for an efficient, elegant and scalable way of applying this binning to a numeric series in a pandas dataframe so that the result includes the respective labels as identified by the binning logic:

Data_input: [3.5, 1, 0.5, 3]

Data_result: ['third', 'first', 'first', 'third']

I tried with pandas.IntervalIndex.from_tuples() followed by pandas.cut(). However, the labels argument of pandas.cut() is disabled when using IntervalIndex.from_tuples() while the name argument of the latter doesn't allow me to set labels to be used as replacement values.

PS: The pandas problem with labels not supported with IntervalIndex has been discussed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21233).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## If all intervals are closed on the same side

The simplest way is to use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html). However, there is an [outstanding bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21233) where it ignores `labels` when `bins` is `IntervalIndex`.

```
def cut(array, bins, labels, closed='right'):
    _bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(bins, closed=closed)

    x = pd.cut(array, _bins)
    x.categories = labels # workaround for the bug
    return x

array = [3.5, 1, 0.5, 3]
bins = [(0,1), (1,2), (3,4)]
labels = ['first', 'second', 'third']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': array,
    'category': cut(array, bins, labels, closed='right')
})
```

Output:

```
   value category
0    3.5    third
1    1.0    first
2    0.5    first
3    3.0      NaN
```

---

## If every interval is different

Things get a lot slower because the code is not vectorized but it's conceptually simple: for each item in the array, find the first bin that it falls into and add the label of that bin.

```
def cut(array, bins, labels):
    intervals = [pd.Interval(*b) for b in bins]

    categories = []
    for value in array:
        cat = None
        for i, interval in enumerate(intervals):
            if value in interval:
                cat = labels[i]
                break
        categories.append(cat)

    return categories

cut([3.5, 1, 0.5, 3], bins=[(0,1,'right'),(1,2,'right'),(3,4,'left')], labels=['first', 'second', 'third'])
```

I modified the bin tuples to include what side they are closed on. Options are `left`, `right`, `both` and `neither`.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer assumes that every interval is closed in the same way. I need full control of each individual interval to be set as either left, right, both or neither as specified in the question.